# `Could not find a part of the path WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\IA64\burn.exe` even though I don't target IA64

Tags: wix, burn

Since pulling changes, building my InstallerBootstrapper project in Visual C# 2010 fails with:

```
Could not find a part of the path "WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\IA64\burn.exe"
```

Indeed this directory does not exist, but it never did and the InstallerBootstrapper was building correctly before pulling.

- The .wixproj and .wxs have not changed.
- I reviewed the changes but can't seem to find what change could have caused that.
- No file in the whole solution contain the string "IA64".
- I have not updated WiX since a few months.
- Google does return anything with these words.

Any idea what could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

For some unfathomable reason, InstallerBootstrapper was configured to use IA64:

[image: ia64]

This happened when I re-imported the Installer et InstallerBootstrapper projects into the solution. No idea why, but it can be fixed by editing the solution file or using the COnfiguration Manager.

I should have searched for the lowercase string too.